# why is deleted infinite broom not path connected

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, connectedness, path-connected

There are many posts in google about this. I am not from core mathematics background. Deleted infinite broom are lines connecting $(0,0)$ to $(1,\frac{1}{n})$ but point $(1,0)$ is not included.

I know this is NOT path-connected but connected.

If I had to prove that it is not path connected, there should exist 2 points between which no path exists. But in proof why is that $(1,0)$ is considered when it is not part of $X$, where $X$ is the deleted infinite broom.

I understood the definition of path connectedness as any 2 points $x$ and $y$ in $X$, there should be path $P$ (which is continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $X$)

Comment: What you describe in terms of line segments as the deleted infinite broom is indeed path connected. However it it not the usual definition.

Comment: I concur with @mathcounterexamples.net. You might want to go back to the definition for "deleted infinite broom" in the book that you are working from to check that it does actually say what you describe here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mathcounterexamples.net says, the space you describe is in fact path connected. The space known generally as the infinite broom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom) contains the lines you describe in addition to the interval $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ on the $x$-axis, This space is not path connected because it is impossible to join any point on the interval $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ to any point on one of the other lines making up the broom.

Comment: understood now. thank you.